# Building a weakref cache in python

Tags: python, caching, weak-references

I'm currently coding a project in python where I need a sort of cache of generic objects, I have settled on using WeakValueDictionaries for this. These generic objects are often referenced by many other non-generic objects. My main problem though is that I can't seem to wrap my head around a way of making these WeakValueDictionaries available to many different portions of the program. I would prefer not to use "global" variables if possible.

Best regards

FrederikNS

Comment: Have you tried to persist them in a database or in the file system? Maybe with pickle?

Comment: The thing is, these generic objects are created from a database which is local, and therefore I would like these dictionaries to stay in memory. I just want a way to access it from multiple places in the program during execution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe I'm not understanding your question, but making a dictionary of weakly referenced values available to your code isn't really any different from making a dictionary of anything else available to your code.  I would store a reference to the `WeakValueDictionary` on:

- each instance (referenced via `self`)
- a class (also referenced via `self`, but shared between instances)
- a module (global, kind of)

depending on what made the most sense given the rest of your code.

Comment: You understood exactly what i wanted, my primary mistake was that i used the class variant, where i needed the module one, thanks for making me realise that